# Footer Copyright and Designed by are centered Nav bar is not

Tags: html, css

So I want the nav section to be inline with the other two nav items so it creates a nice all in line centered vertically footer.

However even though the 2nd and 3rd items are in the center the nav bar is touching the bottom of the footer.

code

```css
.footer{
    margin-top: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}
.footer-nav a{
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    position: relative;
}
.mac{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
     <nav class='footer-nav'>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
     <span>Website Designed by <a class='mac' href='https://machooper.com'>Mac Hooper</a></span>
     <span>Copyright &copy Vegan Restaraunt</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.footer{
    margin-top: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}
.footer-nav ul{
list-style:none;
}
.footer-nav ul li{
display:inline;
}
.footer-nav a{
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    position: relative;
}
.mac{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <nav class='footer-nav'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <span>Website Designed by <a class='mac' href='https://machooper.com'>Mac Hooper</a></span>
    <span>Copyright &copy Vegan Restaraunt</span>
</div>
```

Comment: So they are already inline, the problem I am having is that the nav section doesn't line up with the Copyright Section.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your issue. Can you explain or show the issue??

Comment: Right so the nav section (home about etc.) is stuck to the bottom of the footer see image https://imgur.com/dPAOehn

The rest of the nav is in the middle of the footer vertically.

Comment: The solution i provided on your  code....it is working fine. I guess some other css is doing this. Need more css code from you which is getting applied at footer

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code in your style sheet

```
.footer-nav ul li{
display:inline;
padding: 10px; }
```

`display:inline;`

property will align your list items

Comment: i hope this will help you

Comment: So they are already inline, the problem I am having is that the nav section doesn't line up with the Copyright Section.

Comment: im having perfectly aligned items

Comment: can you provide current footer css code